# Custom view for AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, viewgroup

I'm trying to apply a custom view for my `AlertDialog`. My problem is that I'm using `fragment`s, a `listview` with a custom adapter, and my `alertdialog` and I think it's getting the `ViewGroup`s mixed up.

Here's what I have for my `alertdialog`, however it keeps crashing giving me an

> unsupportedoperationexception addview is not supported in adapterview

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_site, (ViewGroup)getActivity().getCurrentFocus());
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialoglayout);
```

Comment: try this `View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_site, null);`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you could give it no ViewGroup

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View dialoglayout = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_site, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    view v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a custom Alert Dialog and use it.

```
public class MyAlertDialog  extends Dialog {

  Context mContext;

  public InfoCustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
    this.mContext = context;
   }



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog_new_site);
  }
 }
```

then use

```
  MyAlertDialog alertDialog = new MyAlertDialog(getActivity());
  alertDialog.show();
```